# What if istikhara for marriage is positive for one partner and negative for the other?

Tags: nikah, istikharah

Salaam Everyone.

My brother's prospective wife has done istikhara and it came out positive.

Does my brother have to do the same and what if it comes out negative?  Can they still marry each other because they like each other a lot?

JazakAllah

Comment: What is further wife?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to learn more about this site by taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: @Anwar he may mean the fiancée!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the **Related** posts which appear on the right hand and search on the site by tag [istikharah](/questions/tagged/istikharah).

Istikhara is a known and recommended sunnah of our Messenger (See for example in sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/19))

Of course your brother is encouraged to do istikhara as marriage is a big matter one should try to ask Allah for guidance at. What the result of istikhara for your brother maybe, i can't tell, but if it was positive he may feel good about the marriage. If it was negative it is still his decision whether he wants to marry that girl or not. And he is free to repeat it.